# Text manipulation in Python

Tags: python

I have the following list in Python :

```
[{"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "A", "evidence": []}, 
 {"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "B", "evidence": []},
 {"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "C", "evidence": []}, 
 {"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "D", "evidence": []}, 
 {"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "E", "evidence": []}, 
 {"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "F", "evidence": []}]
```

I want to convert this into :

```
A + B + C --> D + E + F
```

Which is the easiest way to do this in python?

The rules are:

- If the coefficient is negative, I want to treat the corresponding molecule as reactant.
- If the coefficient is positive, I want to treat the corresponding molecule as product.
- Reactants come on the left hand side of the `-->` mark.
- Products come on the right hand side of the `-->` mark.

Comment: That's not a list or a dictionary.

Comment: That depends on the real data structure. Show us the code.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: i am a novice in this area. I was reading other text manipulation questions in python. It was difficult for me to decipher how to do this.

Comment: It is clearly a list as you can see I retrieved the first element as ab[0]

Comment: Proper output would be useful - I'm with @TimPietzcker - I don't see any relationship?

Comment: @user2725924 *It is clearly a list* - is not useful... how does your input relate to your output...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: unfortunately your edit removed the connection between the letters (the molecule names) and the resulting equation.

Comment: Hello tim : I am working on a big excel file. I used openpyxl to parse it. I have many rows in the same format. So, i want to automate this .After that , i will paste the result in notepad . And then, I have to use an input for a particular software.

Comment: @TimPietzcker : Thanks for the edit. It is correct. when the coefficient is negative , I want it as a reactant. If it is +ve, i want it as a product of the chemical equation

Comment: Sorry for posting a silly question, but this question will help a lot of chemical engineers out there like me.

Comment: Actually getting your formula is easy, but your data format is terrible; it looks like all but the last string is a JSON-like representation of a dict but without the trailing `}`.  Voting to reopen because the formula part is straightforward.

Comment: @JonClements : when the coefficient is negative , I want it as a reactant. If it is +ve, i want it as a product of the chemical equation. I hope you would have got it by now.

Comment: Summarise all that has been made in these comments, and add them to your question as way of explanation

Comment: @user2725924: "unicode type" isn't a format.

Comment: @DSM : i have edited the question to make it clear for u.

Comment: I am totally new to this forum. if make mistakes, please forgive me

Comment: @user2725924 -- When you're editing your question, could you perhaps try rephrasing it so what you're trying to do is reasonably clear to people without a background in chemistry? It looks like some of the commenters seem to understand what's going here, but to me, your question is completely opaque. 

For example, what precisely do you mean by `A + B + C -> D + E +F`? Could you edit your question to explain the relationship is between those letters and the rest of the question?

Comment: @Michael0x2a : oK, i AM EDITING THE QUESTION.

Comment: @all : can some one upvote the question. The question is clearly useful for chemical and bio-engineers.

Comment: @Michael0x2a : The qusetion is put on hold by some people 1 hour ago. is there any way you can help me  to make this question rolling

Comment: @user2725924 -- click the "flag" button in the lower-left corner of your question, and click the "It needs moderator attention" button. Within the textbox, briefly explain why you think the question should be reopened + how you improved it, and submit. If a moderator agrees with you, the question should be reopened. Alternatively, you can try posting a request to reopen the question on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). You can read more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: Presumably, the reason it hasn't been reopened is because the question currently doesn't show any attempted solutions, which is one of the criteria when asking for code. I think this is probably answerable now, though.

Comment: @HenryKeiter : ok. thanks for your reply. I will try to update when I can find some improvement in my code.

Comment: @TimPietzcker : can you please tell me why am I getting an error when I run your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do:

```
l = [{"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "A", "evidence": []}, 
     {"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "B", "evidence": []},
     {"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "C", "evidence": []}, 
     {"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "D", "evidence": []}, 
     {"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "E", "evidence": []}, 
     {"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "F", "evidence": []}]

def format_mol_list(molecules):
    # Create lists that will hold the molecules of each type, in order
    reactants = []
    products = []

    # Sort the items into reactants and products
    for item in molecules:
       if item["coefficient"] > 0:
          products.append(item["molecule"])
       else:
          reactants.append(item["molecule"])

    return " + ".join(reactants) + " --> " + " + ".join(products)

print format_mol_list(l)
```

Output:

```
A + B + C --> D + E + F
```

Comment: This looks a lot like what I'd written.  (I branched on whether `abs(coeff)` was 1 or not to handle the case of non-unity coefficients).  I suspect though that the `molecules` line won't quite work for the OP, as I think he had started from a string looking like `{'a': 2}, {'b': 3}`, and had generated the list by splitting on `'},'`, hence the missing `}`s.  If I'm right, then one `ast.literal_eval` call would suffice outside the function to turn it into a tuple of dicts.

Comment: @DSM : I live in paris. Just now, I returned home. I will tell you if the method worked in 12 hrs.Thank you.

Comment: @DSM:     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#143>", line 1, in <module>
    format_mol_list(l)
  File "<pyshell#140>", line 3, in format_mol_list
    molecules = [ast.literal_eval(elem) for elem in l]
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ast.py", line 48, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ast.py", line 36, in parse
    return compile(expr, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    "coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "ATP", "evidence": []
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @DSM:   i got a strange error like this. My list l was like this:   '"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "ATP", "evidence": []', '"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "DDCA", "evidence": []', '"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "MG_287_MONOMER_ACP", "evidence": []', '"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "AMP", "evidence": []', '"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "MG_287_MONOMER_ddcaACP", "evidence": []', '"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "PPI", "evidence": []}']

Comment: @user2725924: I've edited the program to make clear how to use the function and what inputs it is expecting. You appear to have made a Syntax error somewhere when copying the program. Try this version as a standalone program and see if it works. I've tested it on Python 2.7, it should work in Python 2.6 as well.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It works perfectly fine in a standalone program. But, in my case , it says : ValueError: malformed string ; in my case , i do not know how to wrap all list elements with single quotes.if I do for item in newlist:
 '\'' + item + '\''          it says :  TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects

Comment: @user2725924 Then what *do* you have? If you give us data that doesn't correspond to your actual data, how should we write a program that fits? Please edit your question to show *exactly* what data you have.

Comment: @TimPietzcker:   I converted into list using c = eval(b) and l = list(c)

Comment: @TimPietzcker : i need to figure out how to wrap all of list elements with single quotes. If I can achieve it, mission accomplished.

Comment: @TimPietzcker : Sorry tim, I saw the last comment by you , when i was uploading my comment. Moreover, Chat doe not work for me.

Comment: @user2725924: OK, I see your edit. Well, then it's much easier - you already have the data structure you need - no need to `ast.literal_eval()` it. Check out my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
li = ['{"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "A", "evidence": []}',
      '{"coefficient": -5.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "B", "evidence": []}',
      '{"coefficient": -1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "C", "evidence": []}',
      '{"coefficient": 1.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "D", "evidence": []}',
      '{"coefficient": 3.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "E", "evidence": []}',
      '{"coefficient": 4.0, "compartment": "c", "molecule": "F", "evidence": []}']

from itertools import imap
from ast import literal_eval

def eq(li):
    a,b = [],[]
    for d in imap(literal_eval,li):
        c = int(d['coefficient'])
        if c==-1:
            a.append(d['molecule'])
        elif c<-1:
            a.append('%d %s' % (-c,d['molecule']))
        elif c==1:
            b.append(d['molecule'])
        elif c>1:
            b.append('%d %s' % (c,d['molecule']))              
    return ''.join(('  +  '.join(a),'  -->  ','  +  '.join(b)))

print eq(li)
```

result

```
A  +  5 B  +  C  -->  D  +  3 E  +  4 F
```